# PHP pass variables between functions - Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to pass a variable from one function to another in the same class, the purpose is to use it in a query.

I tried them all, $this, var_dump, fetch_assoc, ecc

How can I pass the $result variable in the query of the function due() ?

```
<?php
class modUno
{     
    public static function Uno()
    {   
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
        $query = "SELECT id AS memTotal FROM #__users WHERE username = 'bruno';";

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->query();
        return $result->fetch_object()->memTotal;
    }

    public static function due()
    {
        $result->due();

        $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
        $query = "SELECT avatar AS memTotal FROM #__comprofiler WHERE id = '$result';";

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $resulta = $db->query();
        return $resulta->fetch_object()->memTotal;
    }
}
?>
```

sorry I have not actually specified well, what I'm trying to do is a module joomla 3.2, therefore consists of three files the one above is the "helper.php" contains the helper class which is used to do retrieving the information, then there's the "mod_chat.php" that perform initialization routines, call helper routines to collect data, finally, there is "default.php" that will take the data from mod_chat.php and generate the HTML!

mod_chat

```
enter code here

<?php

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php' );

$risultato = modUno::uno();
$foto = modUno::due();
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_chat');
?>
```

default.php

```
enter code here


<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); ?>

<p> risultato: <?php echo $risultato; ?></p>
<p> foto:<img src="http://somesite.com/images/comprofiler/<?php echo $foto; ?>" /></p>
```

I thank you all the rapid responses, I tried to make the changes that you suggested but keeps giving me error, now I will answer one by one on reported errors 
thanks again you are a great comunity

Comment: set a property then assign to it

Comment: why are your methods static?

Answer (score 4):

When you want to share a variable among different methods of your class (without passing the variable as a parameter to each method), then the simplest way is to declare the variable as a class member.

E.g.

```
class myClass {
   private $classVar;

   function someMethod() {
     $this->classVar = "something";
   }

   function anotherMethod() {
     echo $this->classVar;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    class modUno
{  
protected $result;  
public static function Uno()
{   
$db = JFactory::getDBO();   
$query = "SELECT id AS memTotal FROM #__users WHERE username = 'bruno';";

$db->setQuery($query);
$this->result = $db->query();
return $this->result->fetch_object()->memTotal;
}

public static function due()
{
$this->result->due();

$db = JFactory::getDBO();   
$query = "SELECT avatar AS memTotal FROM #__comprofiler WHERE id = '$result';";

$db->setQuery($query);
$resulta = $db->query();
return $resulta->fetch_object()->memTotal;
}
}
```

Comment: create a property like this :-)

Comment: the only problem with this is that the functions are static

Comment: hello thank you for your response, I added a bit of information, I tried your method but it returns   Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/messia/public_html/modules/mod_chat/helper.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

Okay - since you didn't post the code that is calling both your functions, here is some psuedo code for you:

```
$result = Uno();

$resulta = Due($result);
```

Next you have to change your `Due()` function to be `Due($result)`

Answer (score 0):

i would refactor all that code to be

```
<?php
 class modUno
 {     

   private $result;
   private $db
 public function __construct()
 {
    $this->db = JFactory::getDBO();
 }
 public function Uno()
 {   

   $query = "SELECT id AS memTotal FROM #__users WHERE username = 'bruno';";
   $this->db->setQuery($query);
   $this->result = $this->db->query();

   return $result->fetch_object()->memTotal;
 }

 public function due()
 {
   $result->due();

   $query = "SELECT avatar AS memTotal FROM #__comprofiler WHERE id = '$result';";

   $this->db->setQuery($query);
   $resulta = $this->db->query();
   return $resulta->fetch_object()->memTotal;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: hello thank you for your response, I tried your method, correcting a small oblivion "," line 6, I added a bit of information, that I had not given, since it is a joomla module requires a static method, then I modified the functions Uno and Due in static, but it returns an error, Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context , on line 15 !  
thank you very much

Comment: yeah static methods cannot return $this as they are called when a class may not be instansiated